# radio buttons not set from viewmodel (knockoutjs)

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0, single-page-application

I had built a page  where i have radiobuttons controls what are seted using ko. All was working fine until now that for some strange reason (maybe a update o k.o from someone in my team) the control is not working. 
To find the error I used the same example from the knockoutjs page in order to make easy.
The layout:

```
<div >
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
<small data-bind="text: $root.spamFlavor"></small> @*this work fine*@
```

and my viewmodel:

```
export var spamFlavor = ko.observable("almond");
```

As you see the radiobutton should get the value "almond" but it doesn't. the way to check my viewmodel (in typescript) is working with my view is looking in the control  what is working fine.

Currently we are using knockout-2.3.0. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Strange, I run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out to me is that you aren't evaluating your statements of "checked" to true or false, which is what it will take to get your radios selected.

try `data-bind="checked: $root.spamFlavor() == 'almond'"` which will evaluate true/false

Answer (score 0):

Try change library of knockout from 2.3.0 to 3.0.0. It seems that there is a bug for handling radion buttons. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/qACa6/1/ with jsfiddle example

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <input type="radio" name="group"
           data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedItem" />
    <span data-bind="text: foo"></span>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedItem)" />
```

with javascript part

```
var ViewModel = function () {
  this.items = ko.observableArray();
  this.selectedItem = ko.observable();   

  var object1 = {foo: 1, anotherValue: ko.observable(1)}
  var object2 = {foo: 2, anotherValue: ko.observable(2)}

  this.items.push(object1);
  this.items.push(object2);

  this.selectedItem(object2);

};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

its not exactly your code but it seems, that problem is the same. Just change version of knockout library...